# php - Add items to a cart from remote address

Tags: php

its a shopping cart site .
 i am saving items in cart by user ip address .

**by this**

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

If 2 users using the website on same ip address then cart mix the item .so tell me what is the alternate method.
session or temp values something .
  and other login cart item shift to the user account.

Comment: $_SESSION is preferable, if not, then use $_COOKIE. Also, this is an opinion-based question and won't last on SO. You might try simply googling your use case and seeing what happens.

Comment: Do **not** identify users by their IP address. It is a very bad idea. Instead you should [use sessions](http://php.net/sessions) to keep track of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION is what you're looking for. The customer IP is not a good idea. I'd recommend using sessions. You can set the "cart id" in the user session OR have the session id in your cart data structure.
This way you'll know which user is the "owner" of which cart.